# Encode and decode SPDT switch over single wire

Tags: transistors, switches

I'm trying to devise a way to connect a device to a SPDT switch *using only one wire*. Specifically, I want to connect a wall switch to some kind of smart home thingy, and I only have a single switching wire and a neutral lead at the site of the switch.

One obvious way of encoding this would be to have one side of the switch connect via a resistor, and the other one directly. The other side would then see either no resistance, some kind of resistance I get to pick, and infinite resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXvCam.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Basically, what to put in the box?

My limited knowledge suggests that I am going to at least need two transistors to pull the wires down to ground. I could then fiddle around with resistors in such a way that when R1 is connected to the box, one of them turns on, and when it's directly connected to ground, the other transistor turns on. But: how to get the first transistor to switch *off* in this case?

Comment: your "neutral" is mains neutral ot a low voltage DC common?  what power sources are  available at the `??` box?  Is it two position SPDT or three position centre off? does the neuitral go to the `??` box?

Comment: you only need to detect the switch in one position ... if it is not detected in one position, then it is in the other

Comment: @Jasen it's mains neutral. At the box I will have mains live, 230V in this case, and also neutral. And yeah the SPDT will need to have centre off, so I do need to detect both positions :(

Comment: PSA: Don't draw neutral as GND.  Neutral is a hot wire that needs to be drawn as part of the circuit.  Ground also exists and is a real thing, but the various world electrical codes require no current be carried on it.  It's a fault-catcher not a backplane. .

Comment: Thanks :) I am obviously not an electrical engineer! I mainly wanted to illustrate my question with a doodle, and the "draw schematic" button seemed to serve my needs. Only, now my doodle pretends to be a circuit, and it is clearly not! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two 24VDC relays as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdrgBO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The COM is wired through the NC contact on RLY3 to provide "break before make". If you don't need that feature you can avoid using the NC contact.

Comment: faster on the draw than me,  I think you mean "break before make"

Comment: @Jasen Right you are, thanks. LOL great minds etc.

Comment: Ah that looks relatively simple, but maybe not very compact.
How does this work exactly? If D1 is selected, D3 ensures no voltage across RLY3 leaving it open, and the opposite for RLY2? And obviously for D2 being selected the reverse. C1 and C2 are for avoiding voltage spikes due to the coil (?) in the relay being de-energized?

Comment: Yes. C1 and C2 filter the half wave rectified AC so the relays get relatively smooth DC. This actually gives you 4 states BTW, both relays can be simultaneously on if the both the switch contacts are connected to the switch com.

Comment: @Jasen except yours does it with AC mains.  Using low voltage is a major improvement.

Comment: @harper, I stopped. comments are disabled on deleted posts for a reason, even this solution needs to survive an open neutral without exploding. IN4007  goes part-way towards that.

Comment: @Jasen Yes, that thought did occur to me. A fuse and a TVS might be a good idea since 230VAC could conceivably appear on N, limited only by whatever other loads are on there.